# Filter array of objects using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, lodash

I have an array of data like this:

```
const data = [
  {Date: '2018010101', color: 'blue'},
  {Date: '2018010102', color: 'blue'},
  {Date: '2018010103', color: 'red'},
  {Date: '2018010104', color: 'green'},
  {Date: '2018010202', color: 'red'},
  {Date: '2018010301', color: 'yellow'},
  {Date: '2018010204', color: 'green'},
  {Date: '2018010305', color: 'blue'},
  {Date: '2018010206', color: 'green'},
]
```

now I want to get an array of this type:

```
const data = [
  {Date: '2018010101', color: 'blue'},
  {Date: '2018010102', color: 'blue'},
  {Date: '2018010103', color: 'red'},
  {Date: '2018010104', color: 'green'},
]
```

so I want to filter the array and get only those objects with “Date” field that contains 20180101*”.

how can I do?
I think I could use lodash to filter the array but I don't know how to set the regex. This is what I wrote:

```
const filterBy = { 'Date': '20180101*' }
const filteredData = filter(data, filterBy)
```

Comment: I think regex is not necessary.

Comment: `data.filter(({Date}) => Date.startsWith('20180101'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this with regex. Here I am filtering based on the dates which have `20180101` as a prefix with anything following as a suffix:

```js
const data = [  {Date: '2018010101', color: 'blue'},  {Date: '2018010102', color: 'blue'},  {Date: '2018010103', color: 'red'},  {Date: '2018010104', color: 'green'},  {Date: '2018010202', color: 'red'},  {Date: '2018010301', color: 'yellow'},  {Date: '2018010204', color: 'green'},  {Date: '2018010305', color: 'blue'},  {Date: '2018010206', color: 'green'}],
      res = data.filter(({Date}) => Date.match(/20180101./g));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

With Lodash there are more than one way to do this. You can use [filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#filter), filter & [conforms](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#conforms), [takeWhile](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#takeWhile) etc.

Here are some examples:

```js
const data = [ {Date: '2018010101', color: 'blue'}, {Date: '2018010102', color: 'blue'}, {Date: '2018010103', color: 'red'}, {Date: '2018010104', color: 'green'}, {Date: '2018010202', color: 'red'}, {Date: '2018010301', color: 'yellow'}, {Date: '2018010204', color: 'green'}, {Date: '2018010305', color: 'blue'}, {Date: '2018010206', color: 'green'}, ]

const regEx = /20180101/g
const ld1 = _.filter(data, ({Date}) => !!Date.match(regEx))
const ld2 = _.filter(data, _.conforms({ 'Date': d => d.match(regEx) }))
const ld3 = _.takeWhile(data, ({Date}) => !!Date.match(regEx))

console.log('filter', ld1)
console.log('filter & conforms', ld2)
console.log('takeWhile', ld3)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With ES6 you could just:

```js
const data = [ {Date: '2018010101', color: 'blue'}, {Date: '2018010102', color: 'blue'}, {Date: '2018010103', color: 'red'}, {Date: '2018010104', color: 'green'}, {Date: '2018010202', color: 'red'}, {Date: '2018010301', color: 'yellow'}, {Date: '2018010204', color: 'green'}, {Date: '2018010305', color: 'blue'}, {Date: '2018010206', color: 'green'}, ]

const regEx = /20180101/g
const es61 = data.filter(({Date}) => !!Date.match(regEx))
const es62 = data.filter(({Date}) => Date.startsWith('20180101')) // just in case

console.log('filter', es61)
console.log('startsWith', es62)
```

I also added the `startsWith` just in case since from your sample data it seems regEx is not exactly needed but you might have not provided all the data.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Array.filter()` with `indexOf()` to check that filter key in the `Date` value:

```js
const data = [
  {Date: '2018010101', color: 'blue'},
  {Date: '2018010102', color: 'blue'},
  {Date: '2018010103', color: 'red'},
  {Date: '2018010104', color: 'green'},
  {Date: '2018010202', color: 'red'},
  {Date: '2018010301', color: 'yellow'},
  {Date: '2018010204', color: 'green'},
  {Date: '2018010305', color: 'blue'},
  {Date: '2018010206', color: 'green'},
];
let filterKey = '20180101';
const res = data.filter(item => item.Date.indexOf(filterKey) === 0);
console.log(res)
```